# Admob account disable after trying to show my first real ad

Tags: android, google-play, admob, adsense

I've integrated **AdMob** in my android app. I've always tested with the test ads on my device. But before uploading my app on **Google Play Store** I tried to see real ads on my real device, but it didn't show me any ads. After a few hours my account was disabled and sent me the following email

> Thank you for your interest in AdMob. After reviewing your
> application, our specialists have found that it does not meet our
> program criteria. Therefore, we are unable to accept you into our
> program.
>
> We have certain policies in place that we believe will help ensure the
> effectiveness of Google ads for our publishers as well as for our
> advertisers. We review all publishers, and we reserve the right to
> decline any application. As we grow, we may find that we are able to
> expand our program to more publishers with a wider variety of content.
> Please note that we may not be able to respond to inquiries regarding
> the specific reasons for our decision. Thank you for your
> understanding.

I can't understand what I have done wrong. After some searching, I've found that it's not mandatory to upload the app in **Google Playstore** for showing ads. I tried to show ads in a real device which is similar to my published app. So I've created a new one. I've gone through the privacy policy of admob and didn't found anything specific related to my problem. So can anyone please tell me **When should I request my first real ad? why my account is disabled? Can I use same address as my previous one in my new account?**

Comment: Can you please notify that have you created another admob account? If yes then what precautions you adopted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as you add     .addTestDevice(Your device test ad id) to AdRequestBuilder

for example    "AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice("FB9F1C3D53382E1666489F5407301E91")
                    .addTestDevice("CDD86067AF6113E56BF2B62A2D28F5DB").build()"

you can request real ads anytime you want. You should see Test Ad attribituon on your ads. Another way you can use Google Test Ad Unit id's until your app published. Even if it is published, you should use test ads on your device.

Comment: Thanks.  So you saying I should not request real ads on my real device any time? Do I have to remove ``addTestDevice("device_id") `` before publishing my app?

Comment: I haven't added ``.addTestDevice("device_id")`` in my code. I've always requested test ads. If I use multiple devices do I have to add all devices id in ``addTestDevice()``?

Comment: You dont need to remove this line even app is published. With addTestDevice("device_id")  this line you can request real ads on your phone also.  But I suggest not to use published version of the app on your phone. Using builded directly from Android Studo version of app more reliable. And be sure you see "Test Ad " attribution on your ads if you use "addTestDevice("device_id")" this line

Comment: Yes you need to add all your devices ids

Comment: Thanks. Another question, Can I use the same address as my previous one in my new account? Any suggestions for my new account?

Comment: What do you mean by "address"?

Comment: My location and address, contact info. After searching I've found that If any AdMob account is disabled all linked accounts will be disabled. Is there any risk in my case if i use same address as my disabled account?

Comment: Ahh, got it now. I am not sure for this. But I think it shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with showing real ads in your device. It may be for some other reason.

I feel, you or anybody with same eMail or Mobile or IP address or Mac address or anything common, have either suspended or rejected AdMob or Adsense account.

Exact reason is very difficult to find but I'm pretty sure it's not the showing real ads on your device.

Answer (score 0):

> It is nothing to do with test ads or any code implementation done
>   wrong

Google somehow dont trust your app or google account 
or maybe the app quality is not good or the app is not so old. Their verification is automatic ,i was approved always before july 2019. The verfication for new account is automatic after you fill the payment section. I was always approved after 24 hours. They rejected me first time , my app is 1.5 years old , google account is 9 month old. but google phone number linked with gmail account was similar to prevoius blocked adsense account. I am still figuring the cause. Please share you experience and cases here.